# How to copy columns by cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am searching for the most efficient way to copy columns from one worksheet to another by cell value in Excel. I have the following table:

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbTrC.png)

And I want to copy columns "Bay/Ocean" and "Creek" in this table:

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk8JM.png)

The "StationID" in Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 should match up.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the key (StationID) unique within Sheet1? Can one key occur multiple times? Please provide an example of what your result would look like.

Comment: A `vlookup` should work. In your Sheet2, B2, put `=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$C$7,Column(),FALSE)`.  Note: This will work if you only have `A1` once, and the values are the same. If you have more, and need to add more variables to the lookup, I'd start looking at `Index/Match`. But, as Ulli says, if you could give more example data, it would help.

Comment: @Ulli, the key (StationID) is unique within Sheet 1 but it occurs more than once in Sheet 2. I would like to see a result where values in column B and C corresponds to keys in column A. I will fill in the desired result in Sheet2 above. Thank you both!

Comment: @BruceWayne, is there a way to write a function in vlookup or Index/Match that commands it to look up values in column A in Sheet1 and if they match with values in column A in Sheet2, then copy and paste the values in the same row from Sheet1 to Sheet2?

Comment: Sure! just wrap an `If()` statement around it.  But I'm not sure what you mean, so could you give an example? Currently, in Sheet2, if it finds a match for `S1` in your Sheet1 column A, it returns the values from B and C.

Answer (score 0):

@BruceWayne has supplied you with the answer.

- open Sheet2
- into cell B2, enter

> =VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$C$7,Column(),FALSE)

- press "Enter"
- copy cell B2
- paste it into B2:C11

Comment: Wow, this is so awesome! Thank you, @BruceWayne